# Constraints on Score & HighScore Glitching

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

When my score and high-score labels are un-constrainted, meaning they have no specific position on the screen, my score label increases as requested by one unit. However, for some reason when I constrain the score label, meaning I have a holding position on the screen, the animations in my app glitch out, and for some reason all cease. From this point on, nothing happens, no animations are in motion, the app is essentially on idle.

My labels that I have are not programatically constrained, they are just normally constrained on the storyboard. I am not sure why this is the issue and am puzzled.

Everything works fine in my app, the problem only starts to occur when either label is constrained.

Below is an example of the score increment.

// Score Setup

`score += 1
scoreValueRight.text = "\(score)"`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Could it possibly be an issue with the y-coordinate in the animation?